# autosize fit does not work accurately when combined with axis exprs Vega lite

Tags: vega-lite, vega

I am building a chart with dynamic data and aiming to display axis labels in a way that is appropriate for each scenario. When I create a chart using 'autosize: fit' and combine it with expr in labelAlign, labelAngle, or labelExpr, at a certain width, the chart will have a fitting issue where a portion overflows outside the view.

As the example below, a part of the chart, namely the legend, is missing, and the legend becomes visible when the width is set larger. If I directly set values for labelAngle and labelAlign instead of using expr, the chart renders correctly.

[vega editor example](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAdxoATemgBsAJgAMS+DTJY0AFh0B2SgE4AzJbFKkDTGwg0AXnDQgAZnSKIDhIamo0smRooIJwfphoAIxaSgBOxqaoyUpuOGgAHEpMbNhsCElaAL5KUHIBUaigSKlQ0f40goK+AMRiZloAQgBiNiDVIM1wKI3tnT19gyNjRUhQANZkqWwMsmo9fgdBTM1tTBEAyiFQEQ06SgFz6L39w6NKEJhbaz6osgyd4z8cgS6AAkrJMHBUkEcGwIiDQA9YntUJ8GHB3jAkDgfiBri1YssQKk4FAEbMuk8Fq8iZCAB7kpDCMjydBQOAQqFBWqCNjQp56GyJACiFiCSJ6gpFYvuwN84Mh0NlEPOXh+iTu-mB50wAE9CehZHzkF1lZgAOpwDIgsx6AwgYSyOAACStJhByXGmDoBtAPL5kqFop04rlYM5Sq1KrVFTNOv1uKNqRNoYhlut2jtSkdLrdmR0ZnGxBocGUbQ+Xzg5vUmlQenGqSQkR+fqQkLIfN1aAA2iBunp8pY9ENLEFulotABhHQAQTEY4GWmFiRnIaU3SGwsnNks+THQxnNi0Yi0Y+FNjEk7Mo-Xk4GZhPbz7NhsZhn+TsY7EooPa77Dm-bcQAAXUMKZMGQPJUF7bo1C0OB8jgPZ13ZOA9Dged1yFJg-DUJ9nhsKAoFPddEjUXcmHnUCQHCUhUloSIez7Ii7X0Mc4EsXcJzHPx4MsOBEjHOCEKQsdsNw-CyIoqjxliMgORRGIkCYOBBEnNheX5PtEgGHTEiGIJBGU1Shm1GMskSbNjMEUyVT1A0QCTFMrJUmywxABUoQUAACCAmwgfgIChGg-EM6zbItPMbSzB1rIAGRoBBAlQfR7W9TBYhnZlWQdOIEhyH04AGJAgpzXwkrCQkCoyuAEqdV0MyyFIQHS2IAHl0g5EFcviIJWrgAAFUJwkYprqtidTNJ6PTdIM8a4Ai+UIx8vzZACoL0lC+aItVbwkkslrCp2+zE2NJk+qO4F03dTN7T5EsIV8YpSnKKzdW2clnrccoZibWAA3QCq1EJSoGzYZQhrCG4CneXUEGKQRdp+LQzFh+GNIAFV1HFfHxKAQecOkaAgNo1DKJAIkmgG+0nfJt0nScgjJ5AImrDQYCSFzVKprTuhm-Swtcxbw0VQWTLMvaLK5ty7ITXwnPO6WIuuzJbXtIzXLq3NGuyWLXMhkaGkKPXVISpKPXyNKaHWHmelp+nGYK9YkbQOwnbWNnawO-rbaefm5sOmrhY8iMLqDiX1W9y7ZYchXTUD2Jlai275q1hqbrGhPBuG6HUHycYkCJiBit2NpNnUNA-CZIKC6LgANNoNdU4rSoiXEgaqk2bMEBgIA51Aq8EILpbauijKgwfh6zs3ktAOA6RwLTVHZoly5RSeMRANfPf7g614AERK-vuzsai199vshjMIYxBHIlC+JgBNMv0jUC+N2v2+by31-D77ntT5KG3jWXeQDX5oDRJvfqM9yTz0Xr4IwN1QbjDUG2EqcBMAkxmIvRKzRdRxSQLqLk0FQCYCYIIAA+msXcghUhrD8DYJAbAyAULgMQHQggoCUEnHQLs6BzgAAOaDeQAOIACf5A5HIVQmhdC-CWDWAARxgBQpgWhiAID8JQAaWw1AMDJBQgAckgBAuIRFtTivvPq0jqH5FofQywNgYCKIoRANQnh8iJEoDOAAsm1AAqoYjGriGA-RADoOwZh8haEtnaO0yxSE2NkfQxhzDWHsM4dw3hvgBpYlkN5DGMAaCAH68fKLUkl2LkQo5Rqj1GaO0bo-RmAjEmNxOcUEcUABqwoABK1jKG2PsfIpxLi3EeK8b4gJQSQlhMSEKRIlgIlxL0Ak8pAzkkMKYSwthHCuE8L1L4Z0AjvKGMAJt4NB+kyMqQ4pRKi1EaK0TotgeiDHGNMb4cxljLmDKqSM1x7jPHeL8YE4JEBQm+ESJ4lG9hlmrLIes65my0k7MyfsvhIAjknPOd8jZ1S7l1MeY015rTfDtK6b0nFiLHHOP+eMoFUzQXgvQAsswL5LBq3idURJCKhmpO2RkvZ2T0C5KbAUoppTKVDLxbUh5DTnlNJae89AnyrFSJ5b8mlYzAWTJBTMiFWg7CGpsKlTlChuVXN5Vs9JuyskHPQIABEBADLeJEE5FNJVVNuTK+pTyXnNLeW0jp3S+lqotRq0ZAKJnAumWC2ZYgdCJDmVoWFXK1mhpSValFgq7UgEEcI8RkjU0-JuTU+53qiV+pJfwwNFKQ1FuGZqiN9LdUxohQ+aJnFk1msLRsvl1rUVCpAE6l1xiLm1txZ60thL5XEqVSAFV7qHF-K1ZGhlermVmAcPkTxnbzV1t7Zm216Kh1kFdaO7tVKJ0Erlb6xVuIMaggxjOQxoJ-E+IXfW8NdKdXRqZSARIFhLCJDEHoDlcKKmWuRQKw9pKhGiIke+6Vk7r0Kv9b4e9j7n2voQ0uxt37GWzLsC+CJMS4ljGArJQhxDuxKSIfyajNE0FtFkJW4I6RkCpHwZRyMQJkxtjaCEVIQU2jwrTUi-luyAA6EnoPoArNDMdF6S0Eqk8hmduI5OMQU1KnD4yVN4bXY5UJKloRemxriaQcgxjjHY2sYTZmnonGcNlXGXUuRekbGtHjP16NQCZFAf4bZcQRDUPPNgfgAAU3YADkKqosKCi2SoNcWovoafS+nxUXQLeVQZgUJ0WRN1sQ8p6TPqUOtMywASiCCVXwfIQsmeohyWohs2h0jaAEVSKJz0QfE5wlTaKw4OQGzkez6A6sREViAaATIWzBBzpEcETp+R6EoJqEIUNIhtVcMQlbOha7E0btZYUC8tI5dCZQJu8dLszkiL6EAcCl4gO8gAPgALzeViJEeg4WctIHC1FnB7HOO0aixVir3kABU3kxD5EoCeHQYhvIAH5vJ6G8qgby-AbArIo65LKxhWRzxO74Ze9AXvvc+2Qb7v3-uA7wQQkHYPIfQ9h-DxHKOovsgjFF9H3kovpHdFFqz4w+GIhLIILrBXcU6c8XpqN+G+qjZAIohgTZ0pthoKQQbuIZwIG2BCby5xwXvEwKsWz6BvBbGq0XQ7rljvwPQMTTpTJ1DhbcIYozUIfttnO8QJk6ImcADJA-eQAITheC6FiLbgdTpEiN73LCALvWQqz5KLABSUHYfXvvf4IkcHwfvLKQgG7tgHv4Ze7O0nv3Pc4BM7e95RIcTkfeRJDgIy7JwtebbAn33-uMR84UKtiAoO08iLi3zgYWeMdV+T65Jm5MIhtSuEKq26xl+rFX6DJQdI2oHCCuSDrEvfBS8U-ih5KnStqcVzjQ0ZQJvxxkKkEEfxOjvF83d5mFNWS9nnUoRLNaIAqWmGb65G4w-o-IpCSuRoSUzG8cR+ku4GHqSmF+JW5at62uOS5arq7y7+M2bQHm8kTE-Yg4w43844U4s4mEfYi4y4q4IESgX+EQTEf+Oa1awaQBD6aWWG5G2Y5ACktuqk9up2PuSel2QQ90XUT0JQ30TMNAJIZI7AOUMA90ngwI502+LUbAGk3oUE9GCBJ+SB6akGkm0mw2LUSu42cBmB6AA2KaBh6Ap+Uql6qBqmFauBFht+IAVhk2-UWB06mAOBPg9h4uiB6qi6Daum0m+mLaI2XhKuaudAGuWu80vguu+ugRRur0WovGmAWMXhfwFe3GZ03UQ+egoUlQYB1EJIMgggWuMw02d2EBvgkeOIuwUhyC5GQAA)

##### width: 620

[image]

##### width: 640

[image]